# Reference a Column in a Table Variable in Function

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I'm Trying to learn PowerBI by designing a Stock Portfolio Analysis App.

Here's the sample data of Table - `Tradebook_1`

| Symbol | ISIN | Trade Date | Exchange | Segment | Series | Trade Type | Auction | Quantity | Price | Trade ID | Order ID | Order Execution Time | CurrentPrice |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IRFC | INE053F01010 | 04-09-2023 | NSE | EQ | EQ | buy | FALSE | 15 | 65.6 | 23012505 | 1.1E+15 | 04-09-2023 10.57 | 142.3 |  |  |  |
| IRFC | INE053F01010 | 13-09-2023 | BSE | EQ | A | sell | FALSE | 15 | 78.32 | 182294200 | 1.6946E+18 | 13-09-2023 15.17 | 142.3 |  |  |  |
| IRFC | INE053F01010 | 19-12-2023 | NSE | EQ | EQ | buy | FALSE | 100 | 95.15 | 20190250 | 1.1E+15 | 19-12-2023 9.16 | 142.3 |  |  |  |
| IRFC | INE053F01010 | 19-12-2023 | NSE | EQ | EQ | sell | FALSE | 100 | 95.75 | 20228314 | 1.1E+15 | 19-12-2023 9.16 | 142.3 |  |  |  |

I'm trying to create a measure which calculates current Portfolio value on the basis of Above Table, `Tradebook_1` by adding stocks with `Tradebook_1 = "buy"` and subtracting `Tradebook_1 = "sell"` and then multiplying it with `Tradebook_1[CurrentPrice]`

Hence, the total quantity of the above stock should be 0 in portfolio value.

Here's the measure -

```
//Current Portfolio Value
//Current Distinct Stocks in Tradebook irrespective of they're present in Portfolio or not.
VAR CurrentStock = VALUES(Tradebook_1[Symbol])

//Current Stock
//Calculate Quantity of Stocks in Portfolio, Add "buy", Subtract "sell
Var AllStockQ = 
SUMMARIZE(Tradebook_1, Tradebook_1[Symbol],"CurrQuantity", SUMX(Tradebook_1, IF(Tradebook_1[Trade Type] = "buy", Tradebook_1[Quantity], - Tradebook_1[Quantity])))
// Using Filter to reference column in Table Var AllStockQ Joining to Tradebook_1 to get CurrPrice
VAR CurrStockQ = 
NATURALINNERJOIN( FILTER(AllStockQ, [CurrQuantity] > 0), Tradebook_1)
//Get Current Total Portfolio Value
VAR PortfolioVal = SUMX( CurrStockQ , [CurrentPrice] * [CurrQuantity] )

RETURN CurrStockQ
```

I'm getting an error for the same.
How does one go about referencing a column in a table assigned to a variable? I googled it and found `CALCULATETABLE` won't work but Filter will.
Need some help with this measure.

**Edit** - I'm trying to use DAX Queryview, my variable `CurrStockQ` is returning a table joined with `Tradebook_1`. I just want to use this variable to calculate the Portfolio Value.

PBIX File - [Here](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/HSygz3Qd#link)

[image: Query View Joined Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not just this? Should the buy price not be the Price column?

```
Measure = 
VAR b = CALCULATE(SUMX(Tradebook_1, Tradebook_1[Quantity] * Tradebook_1[CurrentPrice]), Tradebook_1[Trade Type] = "buy")
VAR s = CALCULATE(SUMX(Tradebook_1, Tradebook_1[Quantity] * Tradebook_1[CurrentPrice]), Tradebook_1[Trade Type] = "sell")

RETURN b-s
```

Comment: Yes, David, this is correct. But I wanted to see like SQL if I can use "Temporary Tables" and get my calculation from the joined table. However, I learned that `CALCULATETABLE` won't filter tables stored in variables due to Context Transition but `FILTER` can be used. So, I was curious if I could use the columns stored in Variables. But it's throwing an error. I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: The Price column is the Price at which the transaction took place not the current Price. I'm calculating the current Portfolio value.